# Encryption using Rijndael AES using 128 bit keys, 16 byte blocks and cipher block chaining

Tags: php, encryption, aes

In our project, I must use the Algorithm AES 128 CBC with the following data:

KEY = "abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789"

IV = "00000000000000000000000000000000"

The text to encryt is

2~1~000024~0910~20130723092446~T~00002000~USD~F~375019001012120~0~0~00000000000~

The result expected is

0D 58 35 AF EB EE 04 C6 DC 24 21 53 8D B7 C3 8A 12 83 97 0E B3 1F 21 A4 7D 2E 3C C6 23 D2 9E F0 46 12 79 C7 AC F9 3B 03 1B E2 B6 9C E4 5C 93 39 55 49 57 F2 9E F6 09 F0 19 EE C9 75 98 3A 03 B5 37 62 2D 7E 0F 19 6B E1 48 F1 C7 CB B8 8E 60 2A

The result text's length is 160 characters.

I tried using many algorithms but all my results are different.

would you encrypt the text with your own method and you validate with the expected result?

Would you paste your results?

This is my test:

```
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

$data_to_encrypt = "2~1~000024~0910~20130723092446~T~00002000~USD~F~375019001012120~0~0~00000000000~";
$key128 = "abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789";
$iv = "0000000000000000"."0000000000000000";

echo "data_to_encrypt: ".$data_to_encrypt."<br/>";

if (($res = mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key128, $iv)) != -1)
{
    // PHP pads with NULL bytes if $cleartext is not a multiple of the block size.
    $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$data_to_encrypt);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    $data_encrypted = strtoupper(bin2hex($cipherText));
    echo "result encrypt: ".$data_encrypted."<br/>";
    echo "len: ".strlen($data_encrypted)."<br/>";
}
```

This is my answer:

data_to_encrypt: 2~1~000024~0910~20130723092446~T~00002000~USD~F~375019001012120~0~0~00000000000~
result encrypt: C9A4E600BAC6FC4F2077FF62DDB5F9BEAB1C9C567A98E6B81373711A4BC0FFE1748F5E26886896AB87CD375567C5466E6A9F4C079AD19B592E080896BCFDB52324F342A9F94AE71FADB1F6820EB57F7B
len: 160

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a static IV? You just destroyed any element of security.

Comment: I received this IV value from our client. I must use it in our encrypt algorithm.

Comment: So this client is expecting the exact same output for every run of the encryption on the same data? Your client needs to either a) learn some basic cryptography principles or b) butt-out and let the professionals deal with security.

Comment: This is only a test in order to validate the encrypted result.

Comment: The way to validate the encrypted result is that it decrypts back to the input text correctly. The actual values of the encrypted text is irrelevant and *should* be different every time.

Comment: The IV is too long btw. It should only be 16 bytes.

Comment: And the given expected result decodes to bogus!

Comment: Please just ask your client exactly how they performed the encryption. Surely that's a better approach than requesting strangers to brute force the answer for you. It looks to me like the remaining questions are: what padding is used, how exactly is the key derived from the key string and what encoding is used when the plaintext string is converted into bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This C program gives the correct result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

int main()
{
unsigned char key[16] =     {0xab,0xcd,0xef,0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef,0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89};
unsigned char iv[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
unsigned char plaintext[] = {
    '2','~','1','~','0','0','0','0','2','4','~','0','9','1','0','~',
    '2','0','1','3','0','7','2','3','0','9','2','4','4','6','~','T',
    '~','0','0','0','0','2','0','0','0','~','U','S','D','~','F','~',
    '3','7','5','0','1','9','0','0','1','0','1','2','1','2','0','~',
    '0','~','0','~','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','~',
};
unsigned char ciphertext[sizeof(plaintext)];
AES_KEY aes;
size_t i;

AES_set_encrypt_key(key,128,&aes);
AES_cbc_encrypt(plaintext,ciphertext,sizeof(plaintext),&aes,iv,AES_ENCRYPT);

for(i=0; i<sizeof(ciphertext); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", ciphertext[i]);
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

`gcc -o test test.c -lcrypto`

`./test`

`0d 58 35 af eb ee 04 c6 dc 24 21 53 8d b7 c3 8a 12 83 97 0e b3 1f 21 a4 7d 2e 3c c6 23 d2 9e f0 46 12 79 c7 ac f9 3b 03 1b e2 b6 9c e4 5c 93 39 55 49 57 f2 9e f6 09 f0 19 ee c9 75 98 3a 03 b5 37 62 2d 7e 0f 19 6b e1 48 f1 c7 cb b8 8e 60 2a`

Your problem is that you need to de-hexify your key and IV strings into bytes before using them.

Comment: Thanks Zindorky, you give to me a new direction about AES 128 bit encryption. I am very happy because I found the response with your advice. Thanks again (Y) God bless you.

Comment: I accept this solution because I had a new idea from this (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I want to thank to all people that send to me one advice,

Now, I share with you the solution to my question,

I hope it also helps to anyone,

```
<?php

function hex2bin($hex_string) {
    return pack('H*', $hex_string);
}

$data_to_encrypt = '2~1~000024~0910~20130723092446~T~00002000~USD~F~375019001012120~0~0~00000000000~';
$key = 'abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789';
$iv = '0000000000000000';

$key = hex2bin($key);
$iv = hex2bin($iv);

$data_encrypted = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data_to_encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
echo "Data encrypted: ".strtoupper($data_encrypted)."<br/>";
echo "Length: ".strlen($data_encrypted)."<br/>";

?>
```

Data encrypted: 0D5835AFEBEE04C6DC2421538DB7C38A1283970EB31F21A47D2E3CC623D29EF0461279C7ACF93B031BE2B69CE45C9339554957F29EF609F019EEC975983A03B537622D7E0F196BE148F1C7CBB88E602A

Length: 160

God bless you